# IPythonにおける自作モジュールの更新について

Tags: anaconda, ipython

自作の関数を.pyファイルに保存し、外のpyファイルから呼び出して用いる際、自作の関数を頻繁に更新したいのですが、外のpyファイルから一度呼び出してしまうと、いくらimportし直しても更新できません。

どのようにすればよいのかお教えいただければと思います。

例えば、自作の関数を保存したファイルを①.pyとし、①を呼び出すプログラムを②.pyとしたとき、②.pyを実行して色々試しながら必要に応じて①.pyを変更したいと思います。

Comment: 実際にスクリプトの例をいただくことはできますか？ ipythonの出番がどこにもないような・・・

Comment: ①と②、何を IPython で試されていて何をエディタで編集されているのか、具体的な作業手順を教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[autoreload](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html)はご覧になりましたか？

例えばカレントディレクトリにこんなスクリプト、 `foo.py` があったとして

```
def say():
    print("hello")
```

ipythonから `autoreload` モジュールを有効にすると:

```
In [1]: %load_ext autoreload

In [2]: %autoreload 2
```

一回目の起動はこんな感じに:

```
In [3]: from foo import say

In [4]: say()
hello
```

このとき `foo.py` を書き換えて:

```
def say():
    print("world")
```

ipythonで続けて`say()`を実行するとこんな感じになります。

```
In [5]: say()
world
```